# How do I see questions in ascending order of votes

Tags: support, search

How do I see questions with lowest number of votes? Furthermore, how do I see questions with votes $\geq 2$, and no accepted answer, but in ascending order?

Browsing such a list seems the simplest way to find questions that might have been missed out enough attention earlier, so I'm surprised if there exists no such list. If not, please tag as feature-request. If there is such a parameter, sorry for not being able to figure it out myself.

Comment: By "votes" do you mean the sum (upvotes)+(downvotes)? or do you just mean score (upvotes)-(downvotes)? or something else?

Comment: [For future reference](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

Comment: @Lord_Farin I didn't know. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search for `is:q hasaccepted:0 score:2` in the search bar. Then you can order by votes or whatever. You can also refine this search by tags.